# Convert string list into int / long list in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have list like this :

```
ciri = ['[7534, 16210, 16820, 6254, 11778, 28630, 22527, 10217,....]', '[7534, 16210, 16820, 6254, 11778, 28630, 22527, 10217,....]'...]
```

can you help me to convert into list like this :

```
[[7534, 16210, 16820, 6254, 11778, 28630, 22527, 10217,....], [7534, 16210, 16820, 6254, 11778, 28630, 22527, 10217,....]...]
```

this is my code

```
cur.execute(sql)
results = cur.fetchall()
ciri = []
for row in results:
    Penciri = row[2]
    Name = row[1]
    ciri.append(Penciri)
out = map(int, ciri)
print out, "\n"
```

but i have error message like this
[image]

Comment: i want to convert from ['[2, 3, 4]','[4, 5, 7]','[1, 2, 3]'] to [[2, 3, 4],[4, 5, 7],[1, 2, 3]]

Comment: Yes, I read it, but if you want people to help you, you should provide first the code that you tried and its not working.

Comment: sorry, my question has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
In [16]: ciri = ['[7534, 16210, 16820, 6254, 11778, 28630, 22527, 10217]']

In [17]: new_list = [[ int(item.replace('[','').replace(']','')) for item in ciri[0].split(',') ]]

In [18]: new_list
Out[18]: [[7534, 16210, 16820, 6254, 11778, 28630, 22527, 10217]]
```